# Android appwidget ViewStub

Tags: android, android-appwidget, viewstub

I am trying to develop a rather complicated appwidget which could change part of it programmatically. Android suggests for such things to use ViewStub widget.

According to [AppWidgets page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) RemoteViews supports ViewStub.

Because when working with RemoteViews I can't `findViewById()`.
So I've tried using

```
RemoteViews.setViewVisibility(viewstub_id, View.VISIBLE)
```

and that works on devices with API > 15.

The problem is, that it doesn't work on older APIs and crashes when inflating layout.

```
Error inflating AppWidgetppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.widgetProvider}): android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class android.view.ViewStub
```

I've tried to look for any mention about API compatibility, but ViewStub should be available from API 1.

**So is there any information about that when we can use ViewStub in appwidget?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a mention about that ViewStub can be in [RemoteViews only from API 16](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#RemoteViews).

Quite buried information though.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but one thing you can also do is, if your app widget is somewhat modular. Add additional views inside of others using `addView`. One thing to be careful of is, you will near to clear all remoteviews for that particular module in between updates or you will ended up with repeated adds.